# What is the best way to transform Excel VBA with forms to a VB.NET Windows Forms application?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, visual-studio

I have written a fully working Visual basic script for excel that uses a User form and an excel template to calculate and create another excel sheet. It is working fine.

Now, I am trying to create a Windows Forms application in VB.NET. I started with manually creating the user form in visual studio item by item. Though it can be done, It is going to take a lot of time. Is there a better way to do this? Can we import the same user form and VB script?

Comment: Code-behind you should be able to import with some modifications. Form, not so much.

Comment: Do you really mean "console" app?  Console is text-based, so any form pieces will necessarily have to be hand-written since there won't necessarily be a one-to-one correspondence to the visual elements.  If instead you mean WinForms or WPF, it will still be difficult---I don't know of off-the-shelf converters offhand---but it's theoretically possible to do (depending on ability to access the definition of the visual layout, which I don't know of for sure for Excel VBA).

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the response. By console app, I meant WinForms (in VB, .NET framework). With some modifications in code, I will be able to transform the Excel VBA code to VB.NET. But, I am in search of a way to import or transform the user form along with the respective code rather than creating it all new.

Comment: also, Can we use the same VBA code to create WinForms app? or it is mandatory that it should be written in VB.NET syntax?

Comment: There is no such thing as VBA in the .NET ecosystem, at least not from Microsoft--- I suppose it may be theoretically possible for a third-party provider to have a compiler for the VBA language for .NET.  There are a lot of similarities and a lot of VBA will go directly to .NET, but there are key differences that you will need to address.

Comment: @Craig So the only option is to go line by line and convert them into VB.NET compatible code?

Comment: I don't know of any alternative.  There may be commercial VBA to VB.NET translators; Microsoft included a free translator (for VB6 projects, but the language is the same) in Visual Studio 2008 but not since.